# How to perform the same operation on several elements in array in doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

SOLUTION: I used a "for each" loop in the doInBackground() method like this:

```
for(MyImage img:params){
    //this time though for each element I saved the result in a ArrayList<> 
    //and returned the ArrayList<> as the result
}
```

Been at it a couple of hours so I guess I'm just tired. Problem solved. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks!

I'm having a really hard time trying to perform the same operation on each element passed in my AsyncTask's doInBackground(). I only end up with one operation and result. The array contains 10 elements.

```
private class ImageComparator extends AsyncTask<MyImage, Integer, Double>{
    private SQLiteImageDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //prepare database
        database = DetailActivity.this.database;
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(MyImage... params) {

        Log.d("doInBack", "doInBack reached");
        //add as record and calc image features
        params[0].createPixelArrayFromBitmap();
        params[0].getRGBFromPixels(params[0].getPixels());
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getrValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.RED);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getgValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.GREEN);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getbValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.BLUE);

        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getrOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.RED);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getgOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.GREEN);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getbOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.BLUE);


        //compare images
        double result = imageHandler.calcEuclideanDistanceBetweenImages(imageHandler.getCurrentImage(), params[0]);

        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Double result){
        Log.d("compare","distance after comparison: "+result);
    }
```

When I execute my AsyncTask I pass an array MyImage[] like this

```
ImageComparator comparator = new ImageComparator();
comparator.execute(imageHandler.getImages().toArray(new MyImage[imageHandler.getImages().size()]));
```

Does this perform the same operation on every element in the passed MyImage[] array? I tried writing a for loop inside the doInBackground method, but that didn't work. I need the result from every calculation made on every image.

The for loop I tried looked like this:

```
for(MyImage img:params){
    //do stuff
}
```

Should I save the result in a list and return the list as the result?

Comment: `doInBackground(MyImage... params)` means that you can use `params` in a `for (MyImage image : params) {...` loop

Comment: But I still only get one result in the end.

Comment: if you are not familiar with `...` syntax then create a method `void foo(String... parameters)` in some class and try to call it, inside that method use the above loop to output the parameters, doing that you will learn how to call `foo` method

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question and then accept it. That way it will be clear what the correct answer is. In that answer, you should show the complete code for your AsyncTask with your foreach() loop implemented. That way it will be much more helpful to others who find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loop, like below.

```
for(int i = 0;i <params.length; i++ ){

        params[0].createPixelArrayFromBitmap();
        params[0].getRGBFromPixels(params[0].getPixels());
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getrValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.RED);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getgValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.GREEN);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcOccurrenceOfValues(params[0].getbValues(), Histogram.colorComponent.BLUE);

        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getrOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.RED);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getgOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.GREEN);
        params[0].getHistogram().calcMeanValueFromOccurrences(params[0].getHistogram().getbOccurrence(), Histogram.colorComponent.BLUE);


}
```

**and replace your each params[0] with params[i]**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a for loop inside the doInBackground() method and for each item in the for loop save the result of the calculations in a ArrayList<> and lastly return the ArrayList<> as the result. Then in the onPostExecute() method iterate through the ArrayList to your liking.

```
private class ImageComparator extends AsyncTask<MyImage, Integer, ArrayList<Double>>{
    private SQLiteImageDatabase database;
    private ArrayList<Double> results;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //prepare database
        database = DetailActivity.this.database;
        results = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Double> doInBackground(MyImage... params) {

        Log.d("doInBack", "doInBack reached");
        for(MyImage img:params){
            //compare images
            double result = imageHandler.calcEuclideanDistanceBetweenImages(imageHandler.getCurrentImage(), img);
            results.add(result);
        }


        return results;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (ArrayList<Double> result){
        for(double d:result){
            Log.d("compare","distance after comparison: "+d);
        }

    }


}
```